# Automatic transmission truck drops in rpm when i left off the gas pedal in top gear

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, rpm, f-350

I have a 1988 Ford F-350 with 7.3 diesel v8 and 3 speed c6 automatic transmission. When i put it in D and im driving at high rpm and take my foot off the gas in 1st and 2nd gears the rpm stays relatively same engine feels like it is still connected to transmission and rotating at same speeds however when in 3rd at high rpm and when i take my foot of the gas rpm instantly drops by around 500 rpm. Why is this happening in 3rd gear only, is there something wrong with my transmission?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is a problem.  What you describe sounds entirely normal.  Generally when I take my "foot off the gas" I expect the engine rpm to drop.

Comment: well yes but not instantly, in other gears the engine is still coupled to the transmission through tc and they rotate at same speed so rpms dont instantly drop they drop slowly. But in third gear as soon as i let my foot off the gas the rpms suddently drop by about 500 and feels like tc is decoupling the engine from the transmission and therefore engine instantly drops 500 ish rpm.

Comment: It's quite possible that there is a torque converter lock-up device and it's either designed to disengage when getting off the throttle in 3rd or there is some issue with it.  But my point is that what you describe doesn't seem all that unusual.

Comment: It doesnt have a lockup clutch. That seemed weird to me because it doesnt happen on first 2 gears but happens only on the third gear.